# OutputStreamWriter is not working in android higher version, How to solve?

Tags: android

This code working in android lower version not higher version. Because `OutputStreamWriter` not working in higher version.How to solve. This code tested with Android emulator 2.2(working) and 4.4(not working).

```
    public class Main extends Activity {    
    String names,numbers,areas,citys;
    ArrayList<GSdemovote> contact_data = new ArrayList<GSdemovote>();
    DatabaseHandler db;
    GSdemovote contact;
    String n,nn,a,c;    
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.home);
        contact_data.clear();
        db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
        ArrayList<GSdemovote> contact_array_from_db = db.getAllGSdemovotes();    
        for (int i = 0; i < contact_array_from_db.size(); i++) {

            //int tidno = contact_array_from_db.get(i).getID();
            names = contact_array_from_db.get(i).getName();
            numbers = contact_array_from_db.get(i).getPhoneNumber();
            areas = contact_array_from_db.get(i).getArea();
            citys = contact_array_from_db.get(i).getCity();
            execute( names,numbers,areas,citys);                            
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), names+numbers+areas+citys, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();          
        }


    }

    public void execute(String names,String numbers,String areas,String citys){

        try {
            n = URLEncoder.encode(names, "utf-8");
            nn = URLEncoder.encode(numbers, "utf-8");
            a = URLEncoder.encode(areas, "utf-8");
            c = URLEncoder.encode(citys, "utf-8");

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        BufferedReader reader=null;
        String text = "";

        String urlParameters =  "?name="+n+"&number="+nn+"&area="+a+"&city="+c;

        try {

            URL url = new URL("http://10.0.2.2:8080/android/tsubba/demovotes.php");

            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
            wr.write(urlParameters);
            wr.flush();

            // Get the response 


         reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
         StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
         String line = null;


            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            text = sb.toString();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {

                reader.close();
            }
            catch(Exception ex) {}
        }
    }       

}
```

Comment: When i debug to execute this line `OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());` its moving to `catch(Exception ex)
        {

        }` so it wont display error message

Comment: Why not print out the exception, so you can see what the problem is?

Comment: First three line of error  `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException` `at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1145)` `at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:84)`

Comment: Looks like some security issue there. I am not android expert but possibly 4.4 has improved security so you might need to find a way around it (ie. proper way).

Comment: A quick googling... You need to do things differently now for network access. http://blog.vogella.com/2012/02/22/android-strictmode-networkonmainthreadexception/

Comment: DUDE awsome its working perfectly,.. thanku so much.. I added `StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();`  
`StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);` these two line above OuputStream Writer. Thanks

Comment: Good. Whilst it works, I think you chose the less preferred way of doing it :). I thought I read that the correct way is to use Android AsyncTask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get current version of device.

```
int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
```

Run StrictMode only Android 2.3 and 2.3 above.

```
if (currentapiVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD){
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
}
```

Credit goes to [anonymous](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2967673/anonymous)